# Flutter, how to refresh my controller and request with getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am creating an app with getx. I have simple GET requests and I show the data to screen. In the detail screen, I put a button to refresh the request, response of request is coming randomly so everytime user pushes the button a different text will be shown. I did not figured out how to do that.

My Controller:

```
class JokeController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var joke = Joke().obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchJoke();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchJoke() async {
    isLoading(true);
    try {
      var chosenCategory = GetStorage().read("chosenCategory");
      var _joke = await Requests.getJoke(chosenCategory);
      if (_joke != null) {
        joke.value = _joke;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

My Request:

```
static Future<Joke> getJoke(String chosenCategory) async {   
    try {
      var response =
          await client.get(Uri.parse(url)).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Joke _joke = new Joke();
        var responseBody = response.body;
        return _joke.jokeFromJson(responseBody);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

In Page (Obx):

```
Obx(() {
            if (jokeController.isLoading.value) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator().reactive(),
              );
            }
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Center(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .1,
                      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .1),
                  child: Text(
                    jokeController.joke.value.value,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .06,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                )),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .2,
                ),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    width: 250,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.88,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                              shadowColor: Colors.orange),
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          onPressed: () {
                            //Refresh the joke
                          },
                          child: Ink(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    end: Alignment.topCenter,
                                    colors: [
                                  Colors.orange,
                                  Colors.orange[200]
                                ])),
                            child: Container(
                              constraints:
                                  BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300, minWidth: 50),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                "SEE ANOTHER JOKE FROM THIS CATEGORY",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .03,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )))
              ],
            );
          })
```

What I tried so far under `onPressed` :

1. `jokeController.joke.refresh();`
2. `setState ((){});`
3. `Get.to(JokePage());`

but none of these worked. Also I am getting the category from GetStorage and I take it when user clicked a category from previous page. That category will not change. Thanks in advance. I also include a picture of the page:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to just again call `fetchJoke()` method on button pressed event.
You can do like this:

```
onPressed: () {
 jokeController.fetchJoke();//Refresh the joke
},
```